# Strange file structure on surveillance DVR

Tags: security, surveillance

I have a 2TB HDD (WD Purple) from a client's surveillance DVR (Night Owl) with a puzzling file structure. The drive has 7,451 256MB files all dated 1/10/2098 23:02. The files are named 0001-7451 with no extension. That adds up to exactly the number of 256MB files that will fit on 2TB with 39MB left over. Looking at them in a hex editor, they have a line or two of seemingly random data and then nothing but 00. 
These don't appear to be video files, which the manufacturer confirms should be H264 or AVI, but I'm wondering if the file structure suggests anything else such as a drive wipe? Thought I would throw this out there and see if anyone has come across it before.

Comment: I own a similar product:
usually the file format is converted to something usable by a tool provided with the dvr. The package should be avallaible from the html interface of the dvr or from the productor's site.
Give a try with vlc but difficult to have success in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Mine has the option to stream via rtsp which I believe will work with QuickTime player and vlc. it may have something to do with that function. I'm not currently close to the dvr so cannot access the menu. But the firmware shows the url constructor starting with rtsp:// it includes the username, pass, stream and channel and a few other parameters.